# How do I write this code according to the swift 3 syntax?

Tags: swift3, swift2

I am trying to get my app to play a sound, and this code was a resource available on my Udemy Course (which is for Swift 2 :( )

```
func playSound(fileName: String, fileExtension: String) throws {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    let dispatchQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)

    dispatch_async(dispatchQueue, { let mainBundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()

        let filePath = mainBundle.pathForResource("\(fileName)", ofType:"\(fileExtension)")

        if let path = filePath{
            let fileData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path)

            do {
                /* Start the audio player */
                self.audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(data: fileData!)

                guard let player : AVAudioPlayer? = self.audioPlayer else {
                    return
                }

                /* Set the delegate and start playing */
                player!.delegate = self
                if player!.prepareToPlay() && player!.play() {
                    /* Successfully started playing */
                } else {
                    /* Failed to play */
                }

            } catch {
                //self.audioPlayer = nil
                return
            }

        }

    })

}
```

I am trying to get my app to play a sound, and this code was a resource available on my Udemy Course (which is for Swift 2 :( )

Answer (score 0):

Here's what the same method implementation would look like in Swift 3:

```
func playSound(fileName: String, fileExtension: String) throws {

    let dispatchQueue = DispatchQueue.global()

    dispatchQueue.async(execute: { 

        let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "\(fileName)", ofType:"\(fileExtension)")

        if let path = filePath{

            do {
                let fileData = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))

                /* Start the audio player */
                let audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(data: fileData)

                /* Set the delegate and start playing */
                audioPlayer.delegate = self
                if audioPlayer.prepareToPlay() && audioPlayer.play() {
                    /* Successfully started playing */
                } else {
                    /* Failed to play */
                }

            } catch {
                //self.audioPlayer = nil
                return
            }

        }
    })
}
```

Some of the changes you can see here:

- Modernized dispatching (`dispatch_get_global_queue` -> `Dispatch.global()`)
- Dropping of the NS prefix (`NSBundle` -> `Bundle`, `NSData` -> `Data`)

You can see a list of other such changes in articles like [these](https://buildingvts.com/a-mostly-comprehensive-list-of-swift-3-0-and-2-3-changes-193b904bb5b1).

Comment: I am still getting errors... for this code:                                    self.audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(data: fileData!), I'm getting 'NSData is not implicitly convertible to 'Data'; did you mean to use 'as' to explicitly covert? And also, for the line: AVAudioPlayer? = self.audioPlayer, i got this:  Cannot convert value of type 'AVPlayer' to specified type 'AVAudioPlayer??'.            PLEASE HELP!

Comment: @AnshGodha Have updated the answer. As already mentioned in the answer,  a major change in Swift 3 has been dropping of the NS prefixes.

Comment: Hey, I'm really sorry but I'm new to this. I have one more error popping up. for                 if let path = filePath{
I'm getting the error: use of unresolved identifier 'FilePath'... Please help me, I REALLY appreciate it :)

Comment: @AnshGodha Sorry, my bad... skipped out on including that line, please check the edit. BTW, I am surprised you are willing to wait 2 days for code that you can find out for yourself by doing a little bit of research.